# More generalized function to convert linear gradient in objectBoundingBox coordinates to userSpaceOnUse coordinates

Tags: svg, transformation, linear-gradients

I need to convert a linear gradient element from `objectBoundingBox` coordinates to `userSpaceOnUse` coordinates. The reason is that the SVG will be rendered by an engine that doesn't support `objectBoundingBox`. Note that the linear gradient is only referenced by one graphical element.

**Input SVG**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="40%" stop-color="yellow" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="60%" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="50" fill="url('#myGradient')" />
</svg>
```

**Coordinate converter**

```
// input {x1: 50, y1: 50, w: 100, h: 50}
// output {rx1: 80, ry1: 35, rx2: 120, ry2: 115}
function convertCoords(x1: number, y1: number, w: number, h: number) {
  let x2 = x1 + w;
  let y2 = y1 + h;
  let gtransform = 2 / (w / h + h / w);
  let xc = (x2 + x1) / 2;
  let yc = (y2 + y1) / 2;
  let dx = (gtransform * (x2 - x1)) / 2;
  let dy = (gtransform * (y2 - y1)) / 2;
  let rx1 = xc - dy;
  let ry1 = yc - dx;
  let rx2 = xc + dy;
  let ry2 = yc + dx;
  return { x1: rx1, y1: ry1, x2: rx2, y2: ry2 };
}
```

**Output SVG**

I replace the coordinates and add the attribute `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="150">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myGradient" x1="80" y1="35" x2="120" y2="115" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#ff0"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#000"/>
      <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#f00"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="50" fill="url(#myGradient)"/>
</svg>
```

The coordinate converter works well for the SVG above, but not for the SVG below. How can the coordinate converter be generalized to work for the SVG below as well?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%"  gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#ff0"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#000"/>
      <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#f00"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="75" y="0" height="150" width="100" fill="url(#myGradient)">
</svg>
```